# VC++ RegSaveKey creates file with 0 bytes?

Tags: visual-c++, registry, save, byte

Can someone advise why the below is creating a file with 0 Bytes? And solutions that correct this? I'm fairly new to VC++.

SE_BACKUP_NAME privilege is taken earlier in other code. - It has been tested and works fine.

Thank you.

```
//save_loc3 = "c:\InstalogRegBackup\backup_20126141314\hklm_hardware.bak"

long resultC1 = ::RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"HARDWARE", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
std::cout << "Value of GetLastError() is: " << GetLastError() << endl; // "0" is output to screen!
std::wcout << "Value of resultC1 is: " << resultC1 << endl; // "0" is output to screen.

long resultC2 = ::RegSaveKeyW(hKey, save_loc3, NULL); //no errors on this line
std::cout << "Value of GetLastError() is: " << GetLastError() << endl; // "0" is output to screen!
std::wcout << "Value of resultC2 is: " << resultC2 << endl; // "1314" is output to screen! (a required priviledge is not held by the client) also saved file is 0 Bytes?!
```

Comment: Return code of 1314 from `RegSaveKeyW` means `ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD`, if that helps.

Comment: Hi, no that doesn't help unfortunately since SE_BACKUP_NAME privilege should be taken currently. Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: I see - so you're doing [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/381055/2065121) first?

Comment: Yes, a colleague wrote some code that implements that - I call

    ScopedPrivilege guard(SE_BACKUP_NAME); 

earlier in the code in the Main function

Comment: using Instalog::SystemFacades::ScopedPrivilege; 

is above it.

Comment: @RogerRowland It seems that the process never took the SeBackupPrivilege, hence why the saving doesn't work.